# How to access in the template, reactive form, an array in an array

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework

I'm a beginner in programming and i try to understand what i'm doing wrong. :)

I've create a reactive Form that contains an array of string that contains a string an an array of string.

it looks like this:
[image]

And the json file looks like this:

```
  public dbData: any =  {
    'ITEMS':[
      {
        'NAME': 'Farine',
        'QUANTITY': ['140', '60']
      }]
  };
```

I arrive to create the FormGroup correctly:
[image]

When i submit it looks correct:

[image]

But i don't arrive to display it in the template correctly :(

page.ts:

```
export class Form2Page implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  itemsForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }

  initForm() {
    this.itemsForm = new FormGroup({
      'items': new FormArray([])
    });
    console.log('From initForm', this.itemsForm);
  }

  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log('Submit : ', this.itemsForm.value);
  }

  onAddItems() {
    const control = new FormGroup({ name: new FormControl(''),
                                    quantity: new FormArray([])});

    (<FormArray>this.itemsForm.get('items')).push(control);
    console.log('Add From', this.itemsForm);
  }
```

Page.html

```
<ion-content>
  <div>
    {{dbData.ITEMS[0].QUANTITY[1]}}
  </div>
  <form [formGroup]="itemsForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">

    <ion-button type="button" (click)="onAddItems()">New Item</ion-button>

    <div formArrayName="items">
      <div *ngFor="let itemsCtrl of itemsForm.get('items').controls; let i=index">
        <h4>ITEMS</h4>

        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <ion-label>Name :
            <input type="text" formControlName="name">
          </ion-label>
          <br>
          <div formArrayName="quantity">
            <div *ngFor="let quantityCtrl of itemsForm.get('items').controls.get('quantity').controls; let j = index">
              <ion-label>Quantity :
                <input type="text" [formControlName]="j">
              </ion-label>
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ion-button type="submit">Submit</ion-button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: what is not displayed correctly? can you add screen shot, or better if you could create a stackblitz, I see multiple issues but not sure if all make trouble. for now change `<div *ngFor="let quantityCtrl of itemsForm.get('items').controls.get('quantity').controls; let j = index"` to `<div *ngFor="let quantityCtrl of itemsCtrl.get('quantity').controls; let j = index"`

Comment: ```Form2Page.html:24 ERROR TypeError: _co.itemsForm.get(...).controls.get is not a function
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (Form2Page.html:25)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23511)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23308)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)```

Comment: OK, then please provide stackblitz

Comment: i tried your solution with ```itemsCtrl.get('quantity').controls```   Now i have no error message anymore but it doesn't display the "field" quantity.

Comment: I will tried to put the code with stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ky6d7x

Comment: thanks for sharing code, in you code I only see you add item to `items`, there is no code to add items to `quantity` also you have no button for that, how you were expecting to add quantities?

Comment: the code is not complete. if you click on new Items you will see it show "Name" but not the field "quantity". And i don't know why.

Comment: because you initiate the quantity with empty array, you need to push some controls to it

Comment: if i understand well, in the method onAddItems() when i push control, it push control only for name and not for the quantity array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code

please see the fixed code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-formarray)

- You need to add controls/form to array, just having any empty form array is not enough
- For loading data into your form, you need to refactor a little bit, because you need to loop through your items and add control/form to your array

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot **@RezaRahmati** now i understand well

Comment: **@SiddAjmera** have also a good answer with a different approach. I would like to put is post as a good answer to but i can only put one :(

Comment: @JBD thanks for accepting my answer, also you can upvote other answers (or even mine) if you like them

Comment: if i can ask one more question. I'm trying to understand your code, and i wanted to know about the method you have write. loadData() and the createItem() is it TypeScript syntax or Angular ? I'm asking because the syntax is unknown for me and i would like to understand it and learn how it works :)

Comment: @JBD that is es6 syntax and is called `parameter restructuring` you could have defined parameters one by one, then also you need to user same order when calling the method, by this way you just pass an object that has this params then you can use it inn your code

Comment: @JBD see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Setting_a_function_parameter's_default_value

Comment: Thanks so much  !! :)

Comment: Hello I got another problem and I've open a new post  
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56888106/error-ts2339-property-items-does-not-exist-on-type-datamodel           If you can give an eye on it, i will very appreciate it, thanks thanks so much !!! :) :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't implemented in Ionic. But you can use the exact same thing in Ionic too:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export interface Data {
  ITEMS: Array<Item>;
}

export interface Item {
  NAME: string;
  QUANTITY: Array<string>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  dbData: Data = {
    'ITEMS': [
      {
        'NAME': 'Farine',
        'QUANTITY': ['140', '60']
      }]
  };

  itemsForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemsForm = new FormGroup({
      'ITEMS': this.formBuilder.array(this.dbData.ITEMS.map(item => this.createItem(item)))
    });
  }

  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log('Submit : ', this.itemsForm.value);
  }

  onAddItems() {
    (<FormArray>this.itemsForm.get('ITEMS')).push(this.createItem({ NAME: '', QUANTITY: [] }));
  }

  addQuantity(i) {
    (<FormArray>(<FormArray>this.itemsForm.get('ITEMS')).at(i).get('QUANTITY')).push(this.formBuilder.control(''));
  }

  private createItem(item: Item) {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      NAME: [item.NAME],
      QUANTITY: this.formBuilder.array(item.QUANTITY.map(item => this.formBuilder.control(item)))
    });
  }

}
```

And in the template:

```
<pre>{{ itemsForm.value | json }}</pre>

<form [formGroup]="itemsForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
  <button type="button" (click)="onAddItems()">New Item</button>
  <div formArrayName="ITEMS">
    <div *ngFor="let itemsCtrl of itemsForm.get('ITEMS').controls; let i=index">
      <h4>ITEMS</h4>
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <label>Name :
          <input type="text" formControlName="NAME">
        </label>
        <br>
        <div formArrayName="QUANTITY">
          <div 
            *ngFor="let item of itemsCtrl.get('QUANTITY').controls; let j = index">
            <label>Quantity :
              <input type="text" [formControlName]="j">
            </label>
            <br>
          </div>
          <button (click)="addQuantity(i)">Add Quantity</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-with-form-group-form-array-and-form-control?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: What is an "export interface" ? and why are you doing this ?

Comment: It's just for type checking.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to understand. I don't see the difference between your template code and mine. (I'm not talking about the button) and i don't understand why in your code the display quantity is and not in mine :(       stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ky6d7x

Comment: `<input type="text" formControlName="name">` should be `<input type="text" formControlName="NAME">`; `<div *ngFor="let quantityCtrl of itemsForm.get('items').controls.get('quantity').controls; let j = index">` should be `<div *ngFor="let item of itemsCtrl.get('QUANTITY').controls; let j = index">`

Comment: I've also added a few methods. There were actually a lot of issues here and there. I refactored the code a bit to make it work. So it required both HTML And TS changes. You might want to use a comparison tool to compare what changed. ;)

Comment: **Thanks a lot @SiddAjmera it helps me a lot !! :)**