# Error TS2339: Property 'ITEMS' does not exist on type 'DataModel[]'

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, model

I get this error message:
TS2339: Property 'ITEMS' does not exist on type 'DataModel[]'

I'm working in IONIC/ANGULAR and doing a reactive Form with a model and getting data from HTTP.

**There is the model (model.ts):**

```
export class DataModel {
    public ITEMS: any[];

    constructor(public NAME: string, public QUANTITY: Array<string>) {
        this.ITEMS = [{NAME, QUANTITY}];
    }
}
```

**There is the code part where the error come from of the form.page.ts**

```
  setItems() {
    const control = this.itemsForm.controls.items as FormArray;
    this.dbData.ITEMS.forEach(element => {
      control.push(
        this.formBuilder.group({
          name: element.NAME,
          quantity: this.setItem(element)
        })
      );
    });
  }
```

**There is the full code form.page.ts**

```
export class Form2Page implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  obsSubscription: Subscription;
  itemsForm: FormGroup;

  public dbData: DataModel[];


  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private storageService: FormStorageService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Get data from DB
    this.storageService.getDBData();
    this.obsSubscription = this.storageService.dbSubject.subscribe(
      (value: any[]) => {
        this.dbData = value;

    // Creating the FORM
        this.initForm();
        this.setItems();
      },
      error => {
        console.log('erreur');
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  initForm() {
    this.itemsForm = new FormGroup({
      items: new FormArray([])
    });
  }

  setItems() {
    const control = this.itemsForm.controls.items as FormArray;
    this.dbData.ITEMS.forEach(element => {
      control.push(
        this.formBuilder.group({
          name: element.NAME,
          quantity: this.setItem(element)
        })
      );
    });
  }

  setItem(value) {
    const array = new FormArray([]);
    value.QUANTITY.forEach(element => {
      array.push(this.formBuilder.control(element));
    });
    return array;
  }

  findFieldArray(field: any): FormArray {
    return this.itemsForm.get(field) as FormArray;
  }

  addNewItems() {
    const control = this.itemsForm.controls.items as FormArray;
    control.push(
      this.formBuilder.group({
        name: '',
        quantity: this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.control('')])
      })
    );
  }

  addNewItem(item: FormGroup) {
    (item.get('quantity') as FormArray).push(this.formBuilder.control(''));
  }

  removeItem(item: FormGroup, qtyIndex: number, itemIndex: number) {
    (item.get('quantity') as FormArray).removeAt(qtyIndex);
  }

  removeItems(itemIndex: number) {
    const form = this.itemsForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    form.removeAt(itemIndex);
  }

  checkArray(itemIndex: number) {
        // Get the quantity array lenght to display the remove ITEMS button
        return ((this.itemsForm.get('items') as FormArray)
        .at(itemIndex)
        .get('quantity') as FormArray).length;
  }

  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log('Submit : ', this.itemsForm.value);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.obsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: what exactly is 
`public dbData: DataModel[];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbData is a `DataModel[]` , you access it as `this.dbData.ITEMS` which for sure doesn't exists. so either you have to

```
dbData : DataModel;

this.dbData.ITEMS...
```

or

```
dbData : DataModel[];

this.dbData.forEach(dbItem => {

   dbItem.ITEMS...
})
```

also I noticed `DataModel` has an array inside, I guess you meant to have one DataModel not an array

Comment: I did the DataModel to create the dbData structure. And I wanted it to looks like this :  ```dbData: any = {
    ITEMS: [
      {
        NAME: '',
        QUANTITY: ['']
      }
    ]
  };```

Comment: so define your `dbData : DataModel = new DataModel('', [''])`

Comment: I resolve the problem by getting the value from the subscription like this ```this.obsSubscription = this.storageService.dbSubject.subscribe(
      (value: any) => {}```   and not like this, at it was   ```this.obsSubscription = this.storageService.dbSubject.subscribe(
      (value: any[]) => {}```       I did like this, if not, I got an error in the template because of the asynchronous data     Thanks thanks thanks so much !!!

Answer (score 2):

since you defined `public dbData: DataModel[]` as an array you should treat it as one.

My guess is you meant to define it as `public dbData: DataModel`, then it will work when you call `this.dbData.ITEMS.forEach(element => {`

Here is the full change:

```
export class Form2Page implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  obsSubscription: Subscription;
  itemsForm: FormGroup;

  public dbData: DataModel;  // #1 change


  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private storageService: FormStorageService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Get data from DB
    this.storageService.getDBData();
    this.obsSubscription = this.storageService.dbSubject.subscribe(
      (value: any[]) => {
        this.dbData = { ITEMS: value };  // #2 change

    // Creating the FORM
        this.initForm();
        this.setItems();
      },
      error => {
        console.log('erreur');
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  initForm() {
    this.itemsForm = new FormGroup({
      items: new FormArray([])
    });
  }

  setItems() {
    const control = this.itemsForm.controls.items as FormArray;
    this.dbData.ITEMS.forEach(element => {
      control.push(
        this.formBuilder.group({
          name: element.NAME,
          quantity: this.setItem(element)
        })
      );
    });
  }

  setItem(value) {
    const array = new FormArray([]);
    value.QUANTITY.forEach(element => {
      array.push(this.formBuilder.control(element));
    });
    return array;
  }

  findFieldArray(field: any): FormArray {
    return this.itemsForm.get(field) as FormArray;
  }

  addNewItems() {
    const control = this.itemsForm.controls.items as FormArray;
    control.push(
      this.formBuilder.group({
        name: '',
        quantity: this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.control('')])
      })
    );
  }

  addNewItem(item: FormGroup) {
    (item.get('quantity') as FormArray).push(this.formBuilder.control(''));
  }

  removeItem(item: FormGroup, qtyIndex: number, itemIndex: number) {
    (item.get('quantity') as FormArray).removeAt(qtyIndex);
  }

  removeItems(itemIndex: number) {
    const form = this.itemsForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    form.removeAt(itemIndex);
  }

  checkArray(itemIndex: number) {
        // Get the quantity array lenght to display the remove ITEMS button
        return ((this.itemsForm.get('items') as FormArray)
        .at(itemIndex)
        .get('quantity') as FormArray).length;
  }

  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log('Submit : ', this.itemsForm.value);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.obsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Finally you should change:

`public dbData: DataModel[];` -> `public dbData: DataModel;`

`this.dbData = value` -> `this.dbData = { ITEMS: value };`

Comment: if i declare it like this ```public dbData: DataModel[];``` or like this ```public dbData: DataModel;``` i have the same error message. It's even worse. :(

Comment: what is the error you're getting when declared as `dbData: DataModel`?

Comment: ```error TS2322: Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'DataModel'.```   and   ```Property 'ITEMS' is missing in type 'any[]'.```

Comment: now i have this error message  ```error TS2322: Type '{ ITEMS: any[]; }' is not assignable to type 'DataModel'.```  and  ```Property 'NAME' is missing in type '{ ITEMS: any[]; }'.```

Comment: there is the code if you want to copy it and compile in under angular or ionic:    https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-jbdioli

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks so much !!! your suggestion help me a lot to find out i just replace ```value: any[]``` by ```value: any```

Answer (score -1):

Ther is the source code with the error you can see in the code in red.

[Source Code with the error](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-jbdioli)